# Export AOSP emulator files after build

Tags: android-emulator, android-source

After a successful build of the AOSP using a non GUI server run's Ubuntu, I want to download the files to my mac or windows and  run it on the Android Studio emulator or any other emulator.

What files do I have to download and how to run it on my mac ?

Answer (score 0):

Download link:https://source.android.com/setup/build/downloading
Build link: https://source.android.com/setup/build/building

after building source code successfully, run the below command:

```
emulator -verbose -show-kernel
```